# how to "easily" modify parents for revisions?

Tags: git, merge, git-svn, git-rewrite-history

I need to rewrite the history of some revisions in order to "hack" some branches that are synced with git-svn (and I mean *revisions* here... don't want to rewrite the whole history of the branches). If we take out the git-svn details, what I have to do is basically recreate the history of a section of a branch redefining the *parents* of the revisions (only the parents are modified, nothing else).

So that you get a clearer picture of what I intend to do: I want to *remove* a number of revisions from a branch and will replace them with a single revision that I will manually create (with commit-tree... I will use the tree from the latest revision that I will *remove* from the branch). Then I will recreate the revisions that are put "on top" of the revisions that I removed. Given that I'm substituting a revision on the history, I can "rewrite" the child revisions modifying their parents to use the new revisions coming out of the "rewrite" process itself (think of it like a cherry-pick or rebase operation..... only that I don't want to do cherry-pick or rebase because I already have the trees from the original revisions themselves I'm trying to rewrite, right?).

It would seem like git **commit-tree** would be the tool that I could use to get this done (I can use the tree object of the revision I want to rewrite and then I will set up the parents of the revision... well, hundreds of revisions) *however* details like message, author, committer are not that simple to define with commit-tree (have to use environment variables, message can be read from stdin). What would be the easiest way if *not* using commit-tree?

Comment: `git replace` has an `--edit` mode that is basically a wrapper around doing a `git commit-tree`, followed of course by writing a `refs/replace/` reference. That seems like the way to go.

Comment: Not scriptable so it won't hold water (need to do this hundreds of times). Now I'm wondering if what I could do is create the objects "by hand" using ```git hash-object``` by using the object that I want to "rewrite" and then modifying its parents to match what I need.

Comment: Ah, well, if you want to do this in script code, there's code in `git-sh-setup` that `git filter-branch` uses to extract all the commit info into the magic env variables. See, eg, `get_author_ident_from_commit` and the filter-branch script, `set_ident` and `finish_ident`.

Comment: `git filter-branch` and grafts are made for this.  Each line in `.git/info/grafts` is a commit id and the ids of the parents you want the local git to suppose it has; git filter-branch bakes the results into a new history.

Comment: After going around trying to find the "best" approach possible for a number of days, I ended up applying the *commit-tree* approach. I will be adding what I did (with a recipe) to https://github.com/eantoranz/git_svn_rewrite

Comment: Not sure what you mean by change a "revision" and not a "whole history of the branches".  A branch is a reference to a single commit.  As humans we think of it as the chain of commits from the head of the branch (the HEAD is just the commit to which the branch refers) back to the first commit.  If you change a single commit, you change the "whole history".

Comment: "if you change a single commit, you change 'the whole history'". Not really... at least not on git (don't know where you are coming from). If I change a revision in the middle of a branch on git (by amending, say) all I would do is branch off from my original branch and not much else would change... if I want to bring over the changes that are on my "original" branch or branches o top of the revision I just ameded, I'd have to cherry-pick/rebase ion top of my new revision.

Answer (score 0):

Follow up on my original question. Remember what it was about in the first place? I want to rewrite history of an svn branch (change *locally*. On the svn repo the branch won't be touched) so that I can create a "real merge" instead of a series of revisions that have no relation to the branch that is being merged.

I ended up creating a solution that is based on git commit-tree. I have already published it on githug in case anybody is trying to achieve the same.

https://github.com/eantoranz/git_svn_rewrite/blob/master/blend-git.txt

Cheers!